# Lightning Web Component Sticky Header - Not able to global do querySelectorAll

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a generic component to stick the header in LWC.

Here is my component.

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <div id="stickyId" class="myStickyHeader">
        <slot>
            <!-- Sticky content goes here -->
        </slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have defined `sticky2` to class for a sticky header.

**Js controller**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Sticky extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        try {
            window.onscroll = () => {
                let stickysection = this.template.querySelector('.myStickyHeader');
                let sticky2 = stickysection.offsetTop;
                console.log('stickysection  => ' + stickysection);
                console.log('stickysection id  => ' + stickysection.id);
                console.log('sticky2  => ' + sticky2);
                console.log('window.pageYOffset  => ' + window.pageYOffset);
                if (window.pageYOffset > sticky2) {
                    stickysection.classList.add("sticky2");
                } else {
                    stickysection.classList.remove("sticky2");
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error =>', error);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this component in another component like.

```
<c-sticky> 
    <div> my header section </div>
</c-sticky>
```

This works well if I have only one instance of `sticky` component on my lightning page with tabs. But when there are multiple instances, it is not applying the sticky2 class on the currenly focused header.

See the image below, I am want to stick the header section of the component in each tab. So when I am in the **Details tab**, its actully applying `sticky2` class to header in Design tab.

[image]

I think there are two problems here.

- Onscroll method is not able to detect which component is currently focused.
- Tried querySelectorAll to get all of the 'divs' on the page. But could not get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Solved my problem with another approach, even I was able to stick the header to the top of the window, I was very difficult to manage the position on various devices, later I got very simple thought in my mind, I wonder why did not I get it earlier.

Firstly, I fixed the headers in each of the tabs, then I put the rest of the things in a scrollable `div` using `slds-scrollable_y`. To enable scrolling we need to have a fixed height, I used media queries to manage height based on device form factor.

So here is the sample code.

```
<div class="fixedHead">
    Header content here!
</div>
<div class="fixedHeithBasedOnFormFactor slds-scrollable_y">
    Content here!
</div>
```

So the user will be able to scroll `fixedHeithBasedOnFormFactor slds-scrollable_y` content only and the header is fixed and page's scroller is disabled as well

Answer (score 2):

The way you select an element is 
`this.template.querySelector`

ie you can only select the elements which are created by you in current component. Encapsulation by locker lwc. You would never be able to access other elements on the page from your component, imagine a rogue app exchange component that can read other markup data.

Thus `querySelectorAll` wont work ever.

A simple solution I can think of is adding an extra attribute inside your sticky component that determines when to show or hide it.

```
<template>
    <template if:true={show}>
        <div id="stickyId" class="myStickyHeader">
            <slot>
                <!-- Sticky content goes here -->
            </slot>
        </div>
    </template>    
</template>
```

JS:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

export default class Sticky extends LightningElement {

    @api show = true;

    renderedCallback() {
        try {
            window.onscroll = () => {
                let stickysection = this.template.querySelector('.myStickyHeader');
                let sticky2 = stickysection.offsetTop;
                console.log('stickysection  => ' + stickysection);
                console.log('stickysection id  => ' + stickysection.id);
                console.log('sticky2  => ' + sticky2);
                console.log('window.pageYOffset  => ' + window.pageYOffset);
                if (window.pageYOffset > sticky2) {
                    stickysection.classList.add("sticky2");
                } else {
                    stickysection.classList.remove("sticky2");
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error =>', error);
        }
    }
}
```

And then show sticky when the current tab is active.

```
<c-sticky show={isCurrentTabActive}> 
    <div> my header section </div>
</c-sticky>
```

Anyways... I am not a big fan of javascript to handle positions. What you can do is just use SLDS [slds-is-fixed](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/position/)

```
<template>
    <div id="stickyId" class="slds-is-fixed">
        <slot>
            <!-- Sticky content goes here -->
        </slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

No need of JS scrolling workaround.

Comment: How can I set `isCurrentTabActive`? As far as I know onselect don't work in LWC

Comment: what kinda tab it is? Standard SF tabs from app builder?

Comment: I am using both tabs, Standard App builder tabs, also `lightning-tab` for subtabs

Comment: @rahulgawale can y ou try `slds-is-fixed`  for now and see if it works for you?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: Actually, I got why it's not working, I am setting `window.onscroll` method in `renderedcallback` of the component, which gets overwritten when the new component is rendered, so when I switch back to the component which is rendered previously, I don't work as  `window.onscroll` is referring to the most recent rendered component.

Comment: Pranay thank you for your valuable response, I actually was overthinking it. I solved my problem with another approach which was simple than what I was trying before.